# StreamReader.Read method introduces \0 characters in between of data from http streaming

Tags: c#, http, stream, streaming, azure-data-lake-gen2

using Azure.Storage.Files.DataLake package, I am reading a csv file from the Azure Data Lake Storage through TextFieldParser(using StreamReader). When calling the "ReadAsync" method of DataLakeFileClient  object, I am encountering the problem.
The problem is even though buffer is 4096 length, only 3390 bytes of data are retrieved. Actually my production code using [TextFieldParser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser?view=net-6.0) object which uses StreamReader internally. In above scenario TextFieldParser object introduces 706 '\0' characters after 3390 bytes. So I am facing issues.

```
char[] buffer = new char[4096];
DataLakeDirectoryClient directoryClient = fileSystemClient.GetDirectoryClient("my-directory");
DataLakeFileClient fileClient = directoryClient.GetFileClient("data.csv");

Response<FileDownloadInfo> downloadResponse = await fileClient.ReadAsync();
DataTable csvData = new DataTable();
using var parser = Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(downloadResponse.Value.Content);
while(!parser.EndOfData) {
    csvData.Rows.Add(csvReader.ReadFields());
}
// csvData contains a cell with null characters in between the actual value
// for e.g., "28\0\0\0\0\0\0\03.25" . instead of "283.25"
```

TextFieldParser uses StreamReader Internally. Simplified version below:-

```
//inside TextFieldParser's Constructor. downloadResponse.Value.Content will be passed as stream
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);

// inside the ReadFields() method of TextFieldParser
int readCount = reader.Read(buffer, 0, 4096);  // readCount will be 3390
```

But *If "OpenReadAsync" method used, there is no issues*. I learned from debuggging that the returned stream type is .

```
Stream downloadResponse = await fileClient.OpenReadAsync();
// actual type of downloadResponse at runtime is LazyLoadingReadOnlyStream
DataTable csvData = new DataTable();
using var parser = Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(downloadResponse);
while(!parser.EndOfData) {
    csvData.Rows.Add(csvReader.ReadFields());
}
//csvData contains all data intact
```

Whereas ReadAsync returned object contains NonDisposingStream. Inner Stream is Azure.Core.Pipeline.RetriableStream.RetriableStreamImpl -->ReadTimeOutStream --> HttpBaseStream --> ContentLengthReadStream.

I am missing something underlying logic of Streams , http networking in c#. Can anyone explain what is wrong with ReadAsync method ? I would appreciate if good resources like books/blog posts about the fundamentals of this issue.

Comment: It almost sounds like you're expecting `Read` to resize the buffer array. It doesn't. The array is still 4096 characters long. Only the first [number of read characters] of the char array will be changed by Read.

Comment: char(0) is a special character, and classically the string termination character. so it would come naturally that any kind of text parser would stop at the first 0 it encounters. what is  your expectation? if you need the zeroes in the buffer, treat the stream as binary, not as text. Is your executed code really the code shown above - since you're talking about a `TextFieldParser`?

Comment: @CeeMcSharpface I've modified the code shown in the Question. I am not using StreamReader directly